# Is Cyprus in Europe?

Tags: europe, cyprus

The [Wikipedia entry on Cyprus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyprus) says its location is in Europe.

However,

- The [entry on Europe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe#Definition) excludes Cyprus.
- This [list of European countries by population](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_European_countries_by_population) excludes Cyprus because it fails to satisfy the requirement that "the majority of the inhabitants live in Europe".

Perhaps it would be correct to say that based on the strict geographical definition of Europe, Cyprus is not part of Europe; but based on the political notions of Europe, it is?

Comment: Wikipedia isn't "truth". It's just a bunch of info random volunteers typed up. The only "correct" answer would be what an official geography source says for the geographic map; and then start quibbling over what the "official" political definition of Europe is :)

Comment: I am aware that Wikipedia is not "truth". Which is why I came to StackExchange, from whence all truth flows.

Comment: Note on Wikipedia: the sources are usually good enough, I afraid when a topic gets into deep details, it may get inaccurate. I would trust Wikipedia in this question since the knowledge is pretty much available for many people so the statements are checked out by many people. This site's real strength is interactivity, the answers you get here might be inaccurate, and other users shall improve the answers or vote the answer down.

Comment: Debating 'truth' is rather pointless, but Wikipedia generally tends to be a well cited resource of information. If there is conflicting information across topics, it's likely that it's due to it simply being a topic with conflicting viewpoints.

Comment: Cyprus is like Melilla, Ceuta, and the Madeiras. Not located in Europe, but culturally, demographically European.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'Europe', it's an abstract concept invented by humans. Hence there is no single right answer.

Comment: As a general rule, SE doesn't have a strict requirement that the newer question be marked as the duplicate of the older question.  A better argument would be that the other question simply doesn't address this question except in a sort of "There is no spoon" way.

Comment: @Brythan: Well, then the duplicate message needs to be changed to something else. Right now it states "This question has been asked **before** and already has an answer."

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Cyprus's position:

**Geographically** it is considered to be in Asia. Here is the [map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Europe_Asia_transcontinental.png).

**Tectonically** it is on a small separate plate together with most of Turkey, is separate from the Eurasian plate, and doesn't belong to the African plate. Here is the [map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Eurasian_plate.PNG).

**Politically** it is, in some sense, in Europe, since it is a member of the EU. But, for example, in the UN, it is considered to be Asian. It is culturally mostly Greek, but has a very notable and separated Turkish minority in the northeast.

**Other:** Cyprus used to be a member of the Eurovision song contest, a member of UEFA Europa League, and as an entrant in the Olympic Games, Cyprus (and even Turkey) is categorized as a European country. Here is the color-coded [Olympic map](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-LRYZYQCqtxk/UBHA3FNH79I/AAAAAAAAAqU/K9XW72rRbes/s1600/olympics_regional_associations_850.png).

So I would say that, in the most common terms, Cyprus is considered to be a country located in Europe, but in some perspectives, Asia, or between Europe and Asia.

Comment: And historically, it was more European than Asian in its Outlook, at least during the Crusades. It's like Malta, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @AffableGeek historically so was "Turkey".

Comment: +1 but Eurovision doesn't really have to do with anything I think, even Israel participate in that show.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of the EU, yes, it joined the EU in 2004 http://europa.eu/about-eu/countries/index_en.htm

Geographically, it lies on the edge of the Anatolian and African continental plates.

Answer (score 1):

Cyprus is geographically in Asia. It is 70km away from the south eastern coast of Turkey and 100 km away from the coast of Syria. Culturally,  Cyprus is  Oriental, just like Anatolia and the Balkans. Its cultural heritage is neither European nore Asian. I don't know what European or Asian cultures mean. There is Western culture and Oriental culture. The Balkans are in Europe but have an Oriental culture while U.S.A. is in America and has a Western culture, so Kossovo has culturally more in common with Turkey while U.S.A. has more in common with Great Brittain. Cyprus belonged to the Ottoman Empire till the second half of the XIXth century and before that, to the Crusaders, Byzantine Empire, Persian Empire and Babylonian Empire, just like parts of Africa, Europe and Asia so... Cyprus shares common foods, music styles, dances and other traditions  with other countries from the Balkans, the Caucasus, Middle East, North Africa and Anatolia. Politically it is part of Europe. But that doesn't mean much because Israel is part of Eurovision and European Champion's League but that doesn't make it European.

Answer (score -2):

Well culturally Cyprus is like Europe but if you look geologically it is surely in Asia.  The border between Asia and Europe is passing through Istanbul in Turkey which is in Europe but the remaining is in Asia.  Cyprus is below Turkey so it is surely in Asia.  But the people of Cyprus says they are in Europe because it is more developed than Asia.

Comment: “Cyprus is below Turkey so it is surely in Asia”. How is this valid to say that Cyprus is in Asia? Then why is Trinidad and Tobago, much closer to Venezuela than Mexico or the U.S, a North American country           “People of Cyprus say that that they are in Europe because it is more developed than Asia” I hope I don’t cause any offence but places like Hong Kong, Shanghai, Singapore, Dubai, Shenzhen and Tokyo could be as developed as any European city